# Coupling 14 AWG without Marettes

Tags: ac, connector, wire

What options are available beyond marettes to join wires together? I am looking for something that holds 3-5 wires and will be within a portable box (ie will hold together if moved around a bit).

Is [this push-in connector](http://m.homedepot.com/p/Contractor-s-Choice-Purple-6-Port-Push-In-Wire-Connector-50-Pack/204071445/?MERCH=REC--mobileweb_pip_rr-1--203734797--204071445-_-N) a fair approach?

[image]

This is apart of a digitally controlled power-bar/box I'm making for an art installation.

Comment: What are marettes?

Comment: @joshjingles  I would also consider *lever nuts* like [this](http://www.amazon.com/Lever-nuts-5-wire-Block-Connector-12-28/dp/B00C18QL2K).  It's easier to remove the wire from a lever nut than from the push-in connector.

Comment: @LeonHeller: marrettes (wire nuts) are things used in North American AC wiring to hold wires together.

Comment: @joshjingles: are you using solid or stranded wire?  I don't think Marrettes are recommended for stranded wire.  I would probalby use crimp-on terminals and a screw terminal block for stranded wire.

Comment: Are you planning on providing a box and strain relief? None of these things are really suitable for use outside some kind of an enclosure, especially if it's not low voltage.

Comment: Thanks everyone. 

Seems like either an "insulated busbar" (fully insulated)... or a Lever Nut appears to be the solution. (@NickAlexeev)

All connections to one point.
Can use solid or stranded, but prefer stranded. 
All within an enclosed box

Lever Nuts it is. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

By *join wires together*, do you mean connect them all to one point, or connect them in pairs? If you are talking about one point, I would recommend a [busbar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busbar), something like [this](http://www.jaycar.com.au/productView.asp?ID=SZ2003) (from my local electronics store). For connecting pairs of wires together resiliently, try using a [screw terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_terminal), which come in 50 bazillion kinds (to find some, try [this](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Screw%20terminal)).

Comment: @NickAlexeev (1) Thanks for adding the link! (2) I was going to turn it into a proper answer once I got the answers to the important questions.

Comment: You're welcome.  The link was there all along.

Comment: @NickAlexeev No, you added it in your edit - I looked at the diff!

Comment: That edit was made way back.  The original version also had a link.  (Just for the sake of historical correctness.  This is actually not very important.)

Answer (score -1):

If these are power wires like electricians deal with, then you might be looking for something called a *wire nut*.  These are plastic "cap" looking thingies that have a springy metal winding inside.  You bundle 2 or 3 wires together, then screw the cap on.  The spring holds the wires together, and the wires end up getting twisted together a bit.

Wire nuts are approved for power connections in junction boxes by the electrical code, so these things really work.  They come in different sizes, and it's important to use a wire nut only for the number and size of wires it is rated for.